# In OSX, external hard drive doesn't automatically mount after computer boots. Fine if unplug/replug

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive

Hopefully that title isn't too long, but I was trying to encapsulate the whole problem. The external drive that I use for my Time Machine backups doesn't seem to mount automatically when the computer starts up. If I unplug the drive and plug it back in, it shows up and performs fine. But when I restart the computer, it isn't there.

I have a second external plugged in, and it seems to have no problems. Any ideas what could be going on and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should mount automatically mount while booting. If it doesn't, something is wrong with the drive, the partition, or with the system. What is the partition file system type?? have you tried repairing the disk using disk utility?

Comment: By "isn't there", do  you mean strictly not showing up as an icon on your Desktop, or is it not showing up in "/Volumes" at all?